# how to fetch data from firebase based on particular value in a node

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have firebase data base as below

projectmasternode

|

```
 -DS

  |
  ----6125675
  |     |
  |      ----department:"xyz"
  |       --projectname:"sad"

  |
  -----72671273
  |       |
  |         --department:"das"
  |         --projectname:"iuh"

  |
  -----7863873
          |
           --projectname:"sad"
              department :"xyz"
```

now how  to get departments data where department= "xyz".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is right in the FB docs. Check here : https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries and take a look at orderByChild combined with another filter, like endAt. Something like

```
var ref = new Firebase("myfirebase");
ref.orderByChild("department").endAt("xyz").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
console.log(snapshot.key());
});
```

Should do it.

Comment: Never did it myself in IOS, but I guess it should be pretty much the same, check here : https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-complex-queries

Comment: It's pretty much the same. And pretty well covered in the docs. Note that `equalTo`  ( `queryEqualToValue` in iOS) would be preferable to `endAt` in this case, since we're emulating `where x = y`.